# Persist selected item between app running sessions

Tags: listview, listbox, wpf-controls

I'm trying to make a behavior applying to Selector inheritors (ListView, ListBox etc) which will restore selected element and focus it on application launching. Also I want to focus selected element when switching between tabs.

The main problem is to find a time point when ListView populated a list, done all its internal activities and is ready to be focused.

I left out the part of behavior which cares about synchronisation of SelectedIndex with persistence system and cleanup code and show only the part refers to the interaction with control.

```
public class PersistSelectedItemIndexBehavior : Behavior<Selector>
{
  protected override void OnAttached()
  {
    base.OnAttached();

    RestorePersistedSelectedIndex();
    AssociatedObject.Loaded += AssociatedObject_OnLoaded;
  }

  private void AssociatedObject_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    AssociatedObject.GotFocus += AssociatedObject_OnGotFocus;

    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Input, new Action(() =>
    {
      AssosiatedObject.Focus();
      ScrollSelectedItemIntoView(
        AssociatedObject.FindVisualChild<ScrollViewer>());
    }));
  }

  private void AssociatedObject_OnGotFocus(object _, RoutedEventArgs __)
  {
    // do it only once on loading control
    AssociatedObject.GotFocus -= AssociatedObject_OnGotFocus;
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Input, new Action(
      SetFocusOnSelectedElement));
  }

  private void SetFocusOnSelectedElement()
  {
    var element = AssociatedObject.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(
        AssociatedObject.SelectedItem) as IInputElement;

    if (element != null)
      element.Focus();
  }

  private void ScrollSelectedItemIntoView(ScrollViewer scrollViewer)
  {
    double position = AssociatedObject.SelectedIndex;
    position -= scrollViewer.ViewportHeight / 2 - 1;
    scrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(position);
  }
}
```

It works when there are a few items in the ListView, but if there are a several hundred items it does not. When `ScrollSelectedItemIntoView` is called `Items.Count` is `0` and `SelectedIndex` is `-1`.

I need a combination of events and states which will clearly indicate that a ListView is ready to operate with it, is ready to scroll to the selected element and focus it.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved a problem.

```
public class PersistSelectedItemIndexBehavior : Behavior<Selector>
{
  protected override void OnAttached()
  {
    base.OnAttached();
    AssociatedObject.Loaded += AssociatedObject_OnLoaded;

    DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(Selector.SelectedIndexProperty, AssociatedObject.GetType())
     .AddValueChanged(AssociatedObject, OnSelectedIndexChanged);

    RestorePersistedSelectedIndex();
  }

  private void OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(Selector.SelectedIndexProperty, AssociatedObject.GetType())
      .RemoveValueChanged(AssociatedObject, OnSelectedIndexChanged);

    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Input, new Action(() =>
      ScrollSelectedItemIntoView(AssociatedObject.FindVisualChild<ScrollViewer>())));
  }

  private void AssociatedObject_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    AssociatedObject.GotFocus += AssociatedObject_OnGotFocus;
  }

  private void AssociatedObject_OnGotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
  {
    AssociatedObject.GotFocus -= AssociatedObject_OnGotFocus;

    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Input, (Action)SetFocusOnSelectedElement);
  }

  private void SetFocusOnSelectedElement()
  {
    var element = AssociatedObject.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(AssociatedObject.SelectedItem) as IInputElement;
    if (element != null)
      element.Focus();
  }

  private void ScrollSelectedItemIntoView(ScrollViewer scrollViewer)
  {
    double position = AssociatedObject.SelectedIndex;
    position -= scrollViewer.ViewportHeight / 2 - 1;
    scrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(position);

    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Input, new Action(SetFocusOnSelectedElement));
  }
}
```